# protocol adapter Error in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
C:\> lsnrctl status
```

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 24-AUG-2016 14:19:47

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried to start the listener or the listener service?

Comment: want to start the listener

Comment: go to services.msc and start the listener services. If it's up,  go to cmd and typ lsnrctl start

Comment: Windows could not start the OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSLISTENER service on Local Computer ERRor: the system cannot find the file specifid this msg show when start services

Comment: C:\>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 24-AUG-2016 23:15:34

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error when go to cmd and typ lsnrctl start

Comment: Look for the error on windows event log and post them on your question (edit it).